# How can I call the GLib threads g_thread_init using JNA?

Tags: java, jna, glib

I'm trying to invoke a function in a native C library using JNA which uses GLib and GLib Threads.  When I attempt to invoke the function, the JVM crashes and the following error is printed:

```
GLib-ERROR **: The thread system is not yet initialized. 
aborting...
```

I'm pretty sure that means the code needs to invoke the `g_thread_init` function in the `gthread` library before invoking the target function. Thus, I defined the following interface to load the `gthread` library...

```
public interface GLibThreads extends Library {

    public static final GLibThreads INSTANCE = 
              (GLibThreads) Native.loadLibrary("gthread-2.0", GLibThreads.class);

    public void g_thread_init(Pointer pointer);

}
```

...and I tried invoking it before the target function...

```
NativeLibrary.getInstance("glib-2.0");

GLibThreads.INSTANCE.g_thread_init(Pointer.NULL);
String flavors = LibSoda.INSTANCE.getFlavors();
```

...but unfortunately, this doesn't work. I still get the "thread system is not yet initialized" error.

I thought my problem might have been related to defining the method to take a JNA `Pointer`. Here's how the `g_thread_init` function is defined in the gthread header:

```
void    g_thread_init   (GThreadFunctions       *vtable);
```

So I tried defining the `GThreadFunctions` struct and passing in `null`. Unfortunately, that didn't make any difference, and I still get the "thread system is not yet initialized" error.

How can I initialize the threading system so I can successfully invoke the target function?

Comment: what do g_thread_supported() and g_thread_get_initialized() return ?

Comment: g_threads_supported() cannot be called from JNA because it is a macro and not a function. I'll give g_thread_get_initialized() a try and let you know.

Comment: Unfortunately, it looks like the version of GLib Threads I have to use doesn't have the g_thread_get_initialized() function (version 2.0).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't load the glib library before calling g_thread_init.

NativeLibrary.getInstance("glib-2.0") explicitly loads glib.  While calling g_thread_init eventually implicitly loads glib (depending on the OS's own dependency tracking), it probably does so *after* setting up whatever parts of gthread that trigger the error if *not* set up.

Answer (score 0):

Don't load the glib library before calling g_thread_init.

When I removed the `NativeLibrary.getInstance("glib-2.0");` line of code, the thread system initialized and the call to the `LibSoda.INSTANCE.getFlavors()` succeeded!

I'm not entirely sure why this worked. I know accessing the `gthread-2.0` library will implicitly load GLib, but I don't know why loading GLib explicitly first causes the `g_thread_init` call to be ignored.

I'll gladly change which answer is accepted to an answer which explains why the above worked.